# Get Volume Guid of EFI partition on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: c#, winapi, wmi-query, uefi, guid-partition-table

I am trying to extract the **VolumeGuid** of **EFI partition**. I have been able to do it successfully on **Windows 10** Machine using WMI query and Via code using **C# ManagementObjectSearcher**. I created a VHD with a GPT partition type  within it I created the following, a recovery partition, EFI system partition and a basic data partition. The following is the WMI query I run in powershell after mounting the VHD. 
I am unable to extract the same in a **Windows 2012 R2** machine. Rest of the partitions volume guid I am able to extract in Window 2012 R2 machine.

**Sample DiskPart script**

```
CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY SIZE=450 OFFSET=1024 ID=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
FORMAT FS=NTFS LABEL="Recovery" UNIT=4096 QUICK 
CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY SIZE=99 OFFSET=461824 ID=c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b
FORMAT FS=FAT32 LABEL="" UNIT=512 QUICK 
CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY SIZE=129481 OFFSET=579584 ID=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
FORMAT FS=NTFS LABEL="" UNIT=4096 QUICK
```

**WMI Query**

```
"Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Msft_Volume"  -Namespace Root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage"
```

In powershell on windows 10, I can see out for the EFI partition as shown below.

```
__GENUS              : 2
__CLASS              : MSFT_Volume
__SUPERCLASS         : MSFT_StorageObject
__DYNASTY            : MSFT_StorageObject
__RELPATH            : MSFT_Volume.ObjectId="{1}\\\\computer\\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/Providers_v2\\WSP_Volume
                       .ObjectId=\"{efe10384-2fc4-11e9-bb16-806e6f6e6963}:VO:\\\\?\\Volume{f2f37b30-47b8-4553-804d-9b14
                       f6b32e1b}\\\""
__PROPERTY_COUNT     : 18
__DERIVATION         : {MSFT_StorageObject}
__SERVER             : computer
__NAMESPACE          : Root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage
__PATH               : \\computer\Root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage:MSFT_Volume.ObjectId="{1}\\\\computer\\root/Micros
                       oft/Windows/Storage/Providers_v2\\WSP_Volume.ObjectId=\"{efe10384-2fc4-11e9-bb16-806e6f6e6963}:V
                       O:\\\\?\\Volume{f2f37b30-47b8-4553-804d-9b14f6b32e1b}\\\""
AllocationUnitSize   : 512
DedupMode            : 4
DriveLetter          :
DriveType            : 3
FileSystem           : FAT32
FileSystemLabel      :
FileSystemType       : 6
HealthStatus         : 0
ObjectId             : {1}\\computer\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/Providers_v2\WSP_Volume.ObjectId="{efe10384-2fc4-
                       11e9-bb16-806e6f6e6963}:VO:\\?\Volume{f2f37b30-47b8-4553-804d-9b14f6b32e1b}\"
OperationalStatus    : {2}
PassThroughClass     :
PassThroughIds       :
PassThroughNamespace :
PassThroughServer    :
Path                 : \\?\Volume{f2f37b30-47b8-4553-804d-9b14f6b32e1b}\
Size                 : 99614720
SizeRemaining        : 99613696
UniqueId             : **\\?\Volume{f2f37b30-47b8-4553-804d-9b14f6b32e1b}\**
PSComputerName       : computer
```

However the above WMI query does not return details for EFI partition when running on the "Windows 2012 R2".  Even the same query run using c# code doesnt work.

1. Is there any restriction on Windows 2012 R2 that prevents it from displaying the EFI partition details?
2. Is there any other way to extract the volume guid of EFI partition?
3. Currently I had to assign a drive letter to EFI partition in order to read it, I would prefer using the \?\Volume{guid} syntax to open the drive and read it programmatically as it will avoid unnecessarily assigning a drive letter.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Try [`Win32_Volume`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa394515(v=vs.85)) class to see if it helps.

Comment: I have tried that as well, dosen't return the EFI Partition VolumeGuid in Windows 2012 R2, where as works fine on Windows 10.

Comment: I can list FAT32 volume (`DriveLetter:  DriveType: 3  FileSystem: FAT32  FileSystemLable:`) on **Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard (Build 9600)**. But I get different result running the same command as yours via PowerShell run as administrator. For me, there is no `AllocationUnitSize`, `DedupMode` etc. So please check if my reproduce operation and system version match yours or not?